# Turn off ListView border mouseover animations

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, styles, controltemplate

`ListView`'s default style animates the border colour to light blue when you mouse over the control. Is there any way of turning this off without replacing the entire control template?

I've tried

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">       
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

This results in a green border, which turns briefly red when you mouse over before fading to light blue. The default animations take precedence.

Am I missing something simple, or is it time for a template override?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to override the `ControlTemplate`, as the default one uses a `ListBoxChrome` element which creates the effect you see. `ListBoxChrome` ignores the BorderBrush property when the mouse is over, as determined by it's `RenderMouseOver` property.

You can still use `ListBoxChrome` if you want, you would just have to remove the `RenderMouseOver` property. Assuming you are using a `GridView` you'd use:

```
xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"

...

<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <theme:ListBoxChrome Name="Bd"
                                     BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                     BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                     RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
                                     SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </theme:ListBoxChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                                Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to remove the focused look, then it probably better to just replace the `ListBoxChrome` with a `Border` element.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I couldn't work out where the animation was coming from even with Snoop. Not really familiar with how the chrome stuff works yet so your answer was extremely useful.